# Python - Stop Variable

Tags: python

I have 3 python modules for a socket application for a robot. The first, "server.py" redirects and interprets the frames. The second "config.py" create a global variable "Stop" = False, editable by the first module. The third, "motion.py" is executed in a parallel process, in this module while "Stop" is egal to False and "i<10", the code inside is executed.

I managed to compare the "stop" variable but only when I reload the motion module. So, when I'm in the while loop, if server.py edit stop variable to "True", it is necessary to call the motion module again for update the stop variable. I want to stop the while loop once server.py edit the variable "stop. I tried to reload the module config but it doesn't works.

*server.py*

```
import config
import motion
#socket creation
if ('Start' in data):
    Motion.start()
if('Stop' in data):
    config.stop=True
```

*config.py*

```
global stop
stop=False
```

*motion.py*

```
import config
import time
i=0
while(i<10 and config.stop==False):
      i+=1
      time.sleep(1)
      *do stuff*
```

Can you help me ?
Thanks.

Comment: I think you should use Threads for this.

Comment: I tried to run "Motion.start()"  with  `p1 = Process(target=Sequence)
                                                       p1.start()` with def Sequence : Motion.start(). But it the same.